# Como formatar data Yii?

Tags: data, yii

Preciso de um exemplo de função de como mudar a data para o padrão brasileiro.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a seguinte função:

```
Yii::$app->getFormatter()->asDate($variavel_para_formatacao)
```

Não esqueça de fazer as configurações necessárias no arquivo **common/config/main.cfg**

```
'components' => [
    //...
    'formatter' => [
        'dateFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        'datetimeFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyy H:i',
        'timeFormat' => 'H:i',
        'decimalSeparator' => ',',
        'thousandSeparator' => '.',
        'currencyCode' => 'R$',
    ],
    //....
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizar a função nativa to próprio PHP:

```
$mode->sua_data = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($model->sua_data));
```

- `date` // Formata uma data para outros formatos
- `strtotime` // Transforma uma String em dateTime (data)

A sua data (provavelmente retirada do banco de dados) vai vir como uma string normal, por isso antes de usar o date é necessário transforma-la em dateTime.
Se uma String normal for passada para o date ele a transformará em uma data deault (01-01-1970).